# Displaying an image via AJAX by adding image path in to src of img tag

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, image

Below I have an AJAX call that I'm using to display user details in a modal, I recently added an image upload for users, however now I'm trying to display the image. After looking online I saw very different ajax calls and nothing applicable to this situation. And to put it simple, I don't know how to add an image to what I have written below.

To display the image I'm thinking something like: $('#user_image').attr(src); but after that i'm a bit lost.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.user_details').click(function(event) {
    var a = $(this);

    // Get ID
    var currentID = parseInt(a.data('id'));

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'ajax_user.php', // in here you should put your query 
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
      data: {
        'user_id': currentID
      }, // here you pass your id via ajax .
      // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
      success: function(json) {

        // Change the ID in modal
        var m = $('#user_details'),
          mBody = m.find('.panel-body');

        // Update new content
        $('#user_id').text(json.user_id);
        $('#user_gender').text(json.user_gender);
        $('#user_profession').text(json.user_profession);
        $('#last_update').text(json.last_update);


        m.modal('show');

      }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<h2 class="pull-right label label-default display-list"> ID<span class="span-modal-text" id='user_id'></span></h2>
<ul>
  <li><b>Profession:</b>  <span class="" id="user_profession"></span></li>
  <li><b>Gender:</b>  <span class="" id="user_gender"></span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: And you cannot return an image in JSON unless it is in DATA-URI format. Instead return a URL to the image you will then return from another image call

Comment: I'm not trying to display an image directly, i'm trying to display the image path in the src of the img tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
var imagesource = json.picture_src;
 $('#user_image').html('<img src="'+imagesource+'">');
```

This assumes `$('#user_image')` is a `<span>`or a `<div>` element.

If it is an `<img>` element, You can do something like this:

```
var imagesource = json.picture_src;
 $("#user_image").attr("src",imagesource);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currencylogo = 'storage/app/'+data.logo;
alert(currencylogo)
$('#sendlogo').attr('src', currencylogo);
```

You can added extra path by following this rules.

Or if your image path is `public/image/123.png`
then try this.

```
$('#sendlogo').attr('src'.data.logo);
```